# focus border color change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am testing **:focus** on the input to change its border to green when selected. Apparently, It doesn't seem to work. I tried checking for typos but didn't find any. (I am new to the world of Developement)
I am trying to make a to-do app that has an input area at the top for adding more tasks. I am aiming for this area to have a border of green color when selected but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
$("ul").on("click","li",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});

$("ul").on("click","span",function(event){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500,function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event){
    if (event.which == 13) {
        let toDo = $(this).val();
        $(this).val("");
        $("ul").append("<li><span>X</span>   " + toDo + "</li>"); 
    }
});
```

```css
#container {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: none;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.completed {
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

h1 {
    background-color: #2980b9;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

li {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #666666;
    background-color: #fff;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

input {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #2980b9;
    width: 315.89px;
    padding: 13px 20px 13px 20px;

}

input:focus() {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #0fff2d;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

 <div id="container">
  <h1>To-Do List</h1>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo">

  <ul>
   <li><span class="delete">X</span>   Go To Potions Class</li>
   <li><span class="delete">X</span>   Buy New Robes</li>
   <li><span class="delete">X</span>   Visit Hagrid</li>
  </ul>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should be `input:focus`, not `input:focus()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mustn’t add the `()` after focus in CSS:

```js
$("ul").on("click","li",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});

$("ul").on("click","span",function(event){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500,function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event){
    if (event.which == 13) {
        let toDo = $(this).val();
        $(this).val("");
        $("ul").append("<li><span>X</span>   " + toDo + "</li>"); 
    }
});
```

```css
#container {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: none;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.completed {
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

h1 {
    background-color: #2980b9;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

li {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #666666;
    background-color: #fff;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

input {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #2980b9;
    width: 315.89px;
    padding: 13px 20px 13px 20px;

}

input:focus {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #0fff2d;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

 <div id="container">
  <h1>To-Do List</h1>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo">

  <ul>
   <li><span class="delete">X</span>   Go To Potions Class</li>
   <li><span class="delete">X</span>   Buy New Robes</li>
   <li><span class="delete">X</span>   Visit Hagrid</li>
  </ul>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```